# Promtail EC2 permissions

Tags: amazon-ec2, prometheus, amazon-iam, grafana-loki

What are the permissions to grant, for the **ACCESS_KEY** and **SECRET_KEY** when setting up Promtail on EC2 machine?

Key / Role ARN will set on *ec2_sd_config* section of YML file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It needs the following IAM permissions:

- `ec2:DescribeInstance`
- `ec2:DescribeTags`

Answer (score 0):

Resolved

Following permissions need be attached

- "tag:GetResources",
- "cloudwatch:ListTagsForResource",
- "ec2:DescribeTags",
- "ec2:DescribeInstances",
- "ec2:DescribeRegions",
- "elasticloadbalancing:DescribeTargetGroups"